# Sending request to a Client using JButton in Java

Tags: java, client, server, lan

I have 10 Clients connected to my server. I have 10 `JButtons` in my server UI. The clientsystems and buttons are named as 1,2,3 to 10.
Now when I click `button1` from my server UI, I need to send a small message to `client1`. I don't know how to achieve this. Can I assign the IP address of a client to a button and then communicate with the client using this IP?

Comment: Clarified the question, removed several typos and correct a few grammatical mistakes. Try to avoid simple mistakes like plural vs. singular in the future. This will help people a lot to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionListener to acheive the result.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String command = e.getActionCommand();
          //use if condition to differentiate your Buttons that you have clicked.

          //other stuff.
}
```